# How to make unique urls for users

Tags: javascript, php

this question isn't about a specific programming problem but instead about how to create a certain functionality for a site I'm working on, so I apologize if this isn't the correct place to ask this type of question.

That being said, I am working on a project that will allow users to make lists and I'd like to implement a way for users to save and share lists similar to the way [flask.io](http://flask.io/) does, in that each unique list will have a url that can be then shared. What would I have to use in order to implement this in my site?

Currently the site is built with js and php, but I have been thinking about learning a framework and implementing it with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unique yoursite.com/username check out [mod_rewrite](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls), to rewrite your URLs in a user friendly fashion. The actual logic will need to be handled by your PHP application, however.

You can use mod_rewrite to change a

```
yoursite.com/mypage?id=foobar
```

into

```
yoursite.com/user/foobar
```

As far as unique IDs go, there's also the [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to generate the unique URLs would be to generate a numeric ID for each list. This would typically be the ID used to store the information in your database. Then you would hash the ID using say an MD5 hash and generate a human readable encoding of the hashed value, for instance by using a Base64 encoding.

The encoded unique IDs generated this way will be appended to the general list request URL which I assume you know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's uniqid() function gives you somehow unique values. Use them to spice your URLs.

In return, check the URL with database and find the associated user.

Store your unique URLs in your user table in a unique indexed field so that if you have a duplicating unique id (which is a very low possibility) your database denies it.

If you want more, share some code that we can play with...